# How to merge two arrays (with subarrays), then sort and limit (in this order) the resultant array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge, limit

I have two arrays (each with 1000 subarrays) which I merged.
Then I have to sort the new merged array and limit it to 1000 lines again.

Hier the codes:

```
$table1 = array(
    [0] => ('0' => 'A', '1' => 200),
    [1] => ('0' => 'B', '1' => 145),
    [2] => ('0' => 'C', '1' => 160),
    [3] => ('0' => 'D', '1' => 120),
    ...
    [999] => ('0' => 'Z', '1' => 135),
);

$table2 = array(
    [0] => ('0' => 'a', '1' => 20),
    [1] => ('0' => 'b', '1' => 145),
    [2] => ('0' => 'c', '1' => 500),
    [3] => ('0' => 'd', '1' => 600),
    ...
    [999] => ('0' => 'z', '1' => 135),
);

    // Merge arrays.
    $mergedTable = array_merge($table1,$table2);
```

and the result is:

```
$margedTable = array(
    [0] => ('0' => 'A', '1' => 200),
    [1] => ('0' => 'B', '1' => 145),
    [2] => ('0' => 'C', '1' => 160),
    [3] => ('0' => 'D', '1' => 120),
    ...
    [999] => ('0' => 'Z', '1' => 135),
    [1000] => ('0' => 'a', '1' => 20),
    [1001] => ('0' => 'b', '1' => 145),
    [1002] => ('0' => 'c', '1' => 500),
    [1003] => ('0' => 'd', '1' => 600),
    ...
    [1999] => ('0' => 'z', '1' => 135),
);
```

With that I have now an array with 2000 subarrays/lines.
I can sort or limit it separately, but I'm not able to do both operations together.

To limit it I could use array_slice, but then I would have only the first 1000 lines and that's exactly the first array = $table1.

```
$limitedTable = array_slice($mergedTable, 0, 999);
```

to avoid that I have first to sort the merged array. I could do this with following function and usort:

```
function sortByOne($a, $b) {
    $a = $a['1'];
    $b = $b['1'];

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($mergedTable, 'sortByOne');
```

with that I have following result:

```
$margedTable = array(
    [1003] => ('0' => 'd', '1' => 600),
    [1002] => ('0' => 'c', '1' => 500),
    [0] => ('0' => 'A', '1' => 200),
    [2] => ('0' => 'C', '1' => 160),
    [1] => ('0' => 'B', '1' => 145),
    [1001] => ('0' => 'b', '1' => 145),
    [999] => ('0' => 'Z', '1' => 135),
    [1999] => ('0' => 'z', '1' => 135),
    [3] => ('0' => 'D', '1' => 120),
    ...
    [1000] => ('0' => 'a', '1' => 20),
);
```

In the reality the keys don't remain the same so we have following result (but that's ok):

```
$margedTable = array(
    [0] => ('0' => 'd', '1' => 600),
    [1] => ('0' => 'c', '1' => 500),
    [2] => ('0' => 'A', '1' => 200),
    [3] => ('0' => 'C', '1' => 160),
    [4] => ('0' => 'B', '1' => 145),
    [5] => ('0' => 'b', '1' => 145),
    [6] => ('0' => 'Z', '1' => 135),
    [7] => ('0' => 'z', '1' => 135),
    [8] => ('0' => 'D', '1' => 120),
    ...
    [1999] => ('0' => 'a', '1' => 20),
);
```

The problem now is that I cannot limit this one. I tried just like that, but then I receive a boolean (?) = 1

```
 $limitedTable = usort($mergedTable, 'sortByOne');

 print_r($limitedTable);
```

and the result = 1

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are passed by reference to sorting functions. This means that passed arrays will be modified, instead of returned as function result.

See [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for more detailed explanation.

To limit your sorted array all you need is:

```
usort($mergedTable, 'sortByOne');

$limitedTable = array_slice($mergedTable, 0, 999);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you assigning $limitedTable to the result of usort?  usort will return true on a successful sort and false for non successful sort, it does not return an array, the first parameter is an array passed by reference.  If I'm following this correctly, wouldn't you just need to do the following:

```
usort($mergedTable, 'sortByOne'); //sort the $mergedTable array
$limitedTable = array_slice($mergedTable, 0, 999); //return array of first 1000 elements 
print_r($limitedTable);
```